# Why am I getting a W-2c form?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-2, form-1040x

I got a W-2c form today from my previous employer (recently changed jobs in 2018), and I read up online that I need to file 1040x to correct these information. My questions are:

1. What are some typical reasons for a person to get this form? Was it something wrong with the company's taxes? Was it a mistake in the pay roll?
2. How do I know if this correction is final? Because this cannot be efile and I don't know if they will issue another correction after I filed this one.
3. How do I avoid getting this form in the future? Is there some kind of due dilligence I could do on my end to make sure I get the correct form and save more time?

Comment: Did you compsre the new form to the original? Did you compsre it to the last paystub of the year?

Comment: Yes, and some numbers are indeed different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What are some typical reasons for a person to get this form? Was it something wrong with the company's taxes? Was it a mistake in the pay
>      roll?

The corrected form is to fix a problem. It could be be related to any box on the form. Generally there is issue with what they reported on the original form, and what they should have reported.

> 2. How do I know if this correction is final? Because this cannot be efile and I don't know if they will issue another correction after I
>      filed this one.

You generally don't know if they will find another mistake.

Keep in mind that when congress makes tax changes late in the calendar year, that can ripple into the reporting rules. In January 2018 Congress passes a budget bill that made changes to the 2017 taxes, thus forcing some mortgage companies to have to reissue 1099's. I know a 1099 and a w-2 aren't the same thing, but that shows that not all corrections are due to mistakes.

> 3. How do I avoid getting this form in the future? Is there some kind of due dilligence I could do on my end to make sure I get the correct
>      form and save more time?

Always save your paystub from  the last check of the year. It should have all the information that will go in the money related boxes on the w-2. If the w-2 you recieve from the company doesn't match, contact them